# How to write a copy constructor to a class which have only parametric constructor no default constructor for its base class?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I am trying to  write a copy constructor for Clib class which is derived from Cotherlib which has no default constructor 
my original code contains a deep copy operation  and wat to right an other c function which  returns object of CLib so  a copy constructor is required
      #include "stdafx.h"

```
    struct IMem
    {
        virtual  void function_f_1() = 0;
        virtual  void function_f_2() = 0;

    };

    class MyMem : public IMem
    {
    public:
        void function_f_1()
        {
        }
        void function_f_2()
        {
        }
    };
    class CDependentLib1
    {
    public:
        CDependentLib1()
        {
        }
        ~CDependentLib1()
        {
        }
    };
    class CDependentLib2
    {
    public:
        CDependentLib2()
        {
        }
        ~CDependentLib2()
        {
        }
    };

    class COtherLib
    {
    public:
        COtherLib(IMem &Mem, CDependentLib2 &objDependentLIb2)
        {
        }
        ~COtherLib()
        {
        }

    };
    class CLib : public COtherLib
    {
    public:
        CLib(IMem &mem):
            m_1(),
            m_2(),
            COtherLib(mem,m_2)  
        {
        }
        ~CLib()
        {
        }
        CLib(const CLib &ObjClib)// here i am getting error
        {
        }
    private :
        CDependentLib1 m_1;
        CDependentLib2 m_2;


    };
    int main()
    {

        MyMem ObjMem;
        CLib objLib(ObjMem);
        return 0;
    }
```

How can i create a copy constructor . i am not authorized to edit the base class code  and add a default constructor

Comment: I don't see why it should be a problem to write a copy constructor if no default constructor exists. For your shown code `A` cannot be constructed because every constructor that you show requires an already existing instance of `A` as an argument. So there is no way to create an instance of `A`. So if you have at least one constructor that does not require an instance of `a` if works [demo on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zlddJRyvcycjNo2k). So please show a [mcve]  of your problem, for which `A(const A &ObjA)` fails and explain what you mean with fail there.

Comment: Please show a [mre], presumably you have a reference member which makes implementing a copy constructor impossible

Comment: class A 
{
    int i;

public:
    A(Someclass & objSomeClass): b(objSomeClass), c(objSomeClass)// Construction of  objects has a dependency of another   class object
    {
               .
    }
    A(const A &ObjA) // here it will fail because class A has no default constructor 
    {
    }   
};

Comment: @HareeshkumarKaiprath Don't past code in the comment section, [edit] your question instead to add that information. And [mcve] means that you are required to create a simple complete code sample that can be copied, compiled and then results in the error you have. Those incomplete code fragments are not helpful to track down your problem, because none of these should result in a problem to create a copy constructor, for a class not having a default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It's time to not get confused and get a good C++ book.

If you're overriding the default copy constructor, you have to copy the elements from the original to copy yourself. Unless you're planning to actually do something in the copy ctor, either don't put the copy ctor at all or if you just want to have a copy ctor for the sake of it:

```
class A 
{
    int i;

public:
    A(int a): i(a) {}
    A(const A &) = default;
};
```

Though having only a copy ctor is a bad practice. Better follow the [rule of 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) or the rule of 5.

Comment: It would be easier to just remove the copy constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza That's why I wrote "if you just want to have a copy ctor for the sake of it" or "better follow the rule of 3 or the rule of 5". But edited still. Thanks